# Adding hours to all the timestamps in a text file

Tags: shell, date, awk, sed

I have the following text file (`file.dat`):

```
random text 2019-10-10 20:22:33.456000^ text random 2019-11-30 23:45:56.789000 random
2019-11-11 21:22:33.456000 random stuffs,2019-10-31 23:45:56.789000
random, random 2019-10-10 20:22:33.456000^ text everywhere 2019-12-31 23:45:56.789000
```

My objective is to add 7 hours to every timestamp ('YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS') in this text file.

The desired output is as follows:

```
random text 2019-10-11 03:22:33.456000^ text random 2019-12-01 06:45:56.789000 random
2019-11-12 04:22:33.456000 random stuffs,2019-11-01 06:45:56.789000
random, random 2019-10-11 03:22:33.456000^ text everywhere 2020-01-01 06:45:56.789000
```

I currently have a solution for this, but it takes up to 1 minute for a text file with just 10,000 lines. My current way is as follows:

```
awk '{ip=$0;while(match(ip,/[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9] [0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]/,a)){ cmd="date +\"%F %T\" -d \"" a[0] " 7 hours \""; cmd | getline b; close(cmd); sub(a[0],b$0);ip=substr(ip,RSTART+RLENGTH)}; print $0}' file.dat
```

This takes way too much time, as my text files can have up to 1,000,000 lines. Besides, I haven't checked yet but I think the `sub` function in there could cause problems.

Therefore, I have been trying to look at other options:

1. using `sed`:

   ```
   sed "s#([0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})#$(date -d '\1' +'%F %T')#g" file.dat
   ```

   Of course it didn't work, giving an error `invalid date \\1'`. Not surprising because I didn't expect the back reference to work inside.
2. Using `awk`:

   ```
   awk '{print gensub(/([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])-([0-9][0-9])-([0-9][0-9]) ([0-9][0-9]):([0-9][0-9]):([0-9][0-9])/,strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",mktime("\\1 \\2 \\3 \\4 \\5 \\6")),"g",$0)}' file.dat
   ```

   I had hopes with this one, but the output was wrong:

   ```
   random text 1970-01-01 06:59:59.456000^ text random 1970-01-01 06:59:59.789000 random
   1970-01-01 06:59:59.456000 random stuffs,1970-01-01 06:59:59.789000
   random, random 1970-01-01 06:59:59.456000^ text everywhere 1970-01-01 06:59:59.789000
   ```

   All the timestamps became 1970-01-01 06:59:59, which basically means `mktime` returned `-1`.

Any other options? Any efficient way (using bash) will do.

Comment: Isn't the timestamp format fixed? Meaning some have a whitespace between date and time, while some have a comma in between.

Comment: All the timestamps in the entire text file is exactly "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" (with a space in between date and time). I chose to omit the milliseconds as it will remain the same when adding hours to the timestamp.

Comment: What about the expression `2019-11-11,21:22:33.456000` in the second line? It contains a comma instead of a whitespace.

Comment: BTW you are spawing the `date` command as a subprocess from within the `awk` script
multiple times, which will be a bottleneck.
It will be efficient to do it with pure `awk` by using `mktime()` and `strftime()`.

Comment: 1. That was a typo, I am sorry.
2. I have used mktime and strftime in my 2nd way, but didn't work, but I haven't tried to replace the date in my currently working solution yet. I'll give it a try. Thanks :)

Comment: Can you be specific about `didn't work` with the error message etc.? Then we may be able to help you make them work (unless your `awk` does not support `mktime()` function).

Comment: @tshiono thanks a lot for your comment regarding bottleneck with date. I changed my current solution to use mktime and strftime instead, and it worked :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '
{
  line=$0
  while(match($0,/[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+ [0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+/)){
     val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
     split(val,array,"[- :.]")
     var=mktime(array[1] " " array[2] " " array[3] " " array[4] " " array[5]" " array[6])+(3600*7)
     new_val=strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",var)
     $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)
     sub(val,new_val,line)
     delete array
     val=var=new_val=""
  }
  print line
  line=""
}
'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
random text 2019-10-11 03:22:33.456000^ text random 2019-12-01 06:45:56.789000 random
2019-11-12 04:22:33.456000 random stuffs,2019-11-01 06:45:56.789000
random, random 2019-10-11 03:22:33.456000^ text everywhere 2020-01-01 06:45:56.789000
```

***Explanation:*** Adding a detailed explanation for above code. Please scroll to a bit right for seeing explanation :)

```
awk '                                                                                                 ##Starting awk program.
{
  line=$0                                                                                             ##Creating variable line with current line.
  while(match($0,/[0-9]+-[0-9]+-[0-9]+ [0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+/)){                                       ##Running a loop till matches found in line.
     val=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)                                                                    ##Creating val whose value is matched sub-string by match func.
     split(val,array,"[- :.]")                                                                        ##Splitting val into array with delimiters - space : and dot.
     var=mktime(array[1] " " array[2] " " array[3] " " array[4] " " array[5]" " array[6])+(3600*7)    ##Changing array values into epoch time adding 3600*7 seconds too
     new_val=strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",var)                                                        ##Creating variable new_val changing epoch time to date format.
     $0=substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH)                                                                     ##Resetting current line value to rest of the line, to remove previous matched values from it.
     sub(val,new_val,line)                                                                            ##Substituting val with new_val in line.
     delete array                                                                                     ##Deleting array here.
     val=var=new_val=""                                                                               ##Nullifying all variables here.
  }
  print line                                                                                          ##Printing variable line here.
  line=""                                                                                             ##Nullifying variable line here.
}
'  Input_file                                                                                           ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```